# Cookies resetting on page refresh but only certain user

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I knocked together an advent calendar for a friend of mine and I use cookies to store whether or not she has "opened" a door - if she has, it shows a thumbnail of the contents. If she hasn't, it shows the "unopened" background. Now, I've had this working fine on my computer and in Chrome, FF and IE for over a month now.

Unfortunately, my friend isn't having the same result. When she loads the page, it shows as pristine and unopened every time. The thing is, when she clicks on it to "open" the door, it updates to show the thumbnail and if I get her to click on the padlock at the top of the address bar in Chrome, it shows that the cookies have been created and the correct one has been updated. Unfortunately as soon as the page is refreshed, it's somehow overwriting the cookie value.

[Before clicking on Door 1 - cookie value is 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCtfg.png)

[After clicking on Door 1 - cookie value is 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF8Cr.png)

And yet when she refreshes the page, the cookie value is set back to 0 again.

I have NO idea what would make it do that. There IS a piece of code that checks if a specific cookie exists and if not, creates the list the cookies, but even disabling that script call doesn't stop the problem. If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate it because I've tried everything I can think of to make sure the cookies are being set properly and I'm not sure why they aren't persisting for her. I've asked her to check setting for storing cookies, extensions, ad blocking/script blocking stuff, antivirus, etc.

We're both using Chrome on Win 10 - it works for me, but not her.

Thanks in advance, I'm sure its something really simple and I'm just being slow-witted.

The website is [here](https://thewinternetsoldier.000webhostapp.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started working spontaneously.